# If $N = \frac{{n_1}(n_1+1)}{2}\cdot{d_1}$, is it possible to have $N = \frac{{n_2}(n_2+1)}{2}\cdot{d_2}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $$N = \frac{{n_1}(n_1+1)}{2}\cdot{d_1},$$
is it possible to have $$N = \frac{{n_2}(n_2+1)}{2}\cdot{d_2}?$$

Here, $d_i, n_i \in \mathbb{N}$, $d_i > 1$ and $n_1 \neq n_2$.

That is,

**Question 1**

> If a number can be represented as a nontrivial multiple of a triangular number, can it then be represented as a nontrivial multiple of *another* triangular number?

**Added January 27 2017**

and

**Question 2**

> If such a number can be so represented (as in **Question 1**), must it necessarily be (a nontrivial multiple of or) the least common multiple of the triangular numbers
>   $$T(n_1)=\dfrac{{n_1}(n_1 + 1)}{2}$$
>   and
>   $$T(n_2)=\dfrac{{n_2}(n_2 + 1)}{2}?$$

Thanks to users Alex Macedo, dxiv, and Stahl for their initial comments!

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question. Maybe $N$ is the product of two distinct triangular numbers.

Comment: @AlexMacedo, that qualifies as an answer!  However, I would be more interested in the case when it isn't.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris $3,6,36$ are all triangular numbers.

Comment: More generally, $N$ could be the least common multiple of two distinct triangular numbers.

Comment: $N_{n,d} = \frac{(n^2 - 1)((n^2-1) + 1)}{2}\cdot d = \frac{(n + 1)n}{2}\cdot\left((n - 1)n d\right)$ is another class of examples for $n > 1$, $d > 1$ ($n_1 = n^2 - 1$, $n_2 = n$).

Comment: These are all very good comments and directly answer my original question.  I invite you to post an answer, and I will accept the best one.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris regarding your second question, I just want to point out that you ask for $N$ to be a multiple of both $T(n_1)$ and $T(n_2)$, for some $n_1$ and $n_2$. This is the same as asking for $N$ to be a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(T(n_1), T(n_2))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\dfrac{n_1(n_1+1)}{n_2(n_2+1)} = \dfrac{d_2}{d_1}$

It follows that 
$\dfrac{{n_1}(n_1+1)}{2}\cdot{d_1} =  \dfrac{{n_2}(n_2+1)}{2}\cdot{d_2}$

Example $T(6) = 21$ and $T(8)=36$. So $\dfrac{T(6)}{T(8)} = \dfrac{7}{12}$

Hence 
$\dfrac{{6}(6+1)}{2}\cdot{12} =  \dfrac{{8}(8+1)}{2}\cdot{7}$

If $n_1$ and $d_1$ are given {It would have been nice if you were a bit more explicit}, then you want to find $n$ and $d$ that solve

$\dfrac{{n}(n+1)}{2}\cdot{d} = \dfrac{n_1(n_1+1)}{2}\cdot{d_1}$

Which can be expressed as

$n^2 + n - \dfrac{n_1(n_1+1) d_1}{d} = 0$

and can be solved by inspection.

### Example

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{4(4+1)}{2}\cdot{3} &=  \dfrac{{n}(n+1)}{2}\cdot{d} \\
   n^2 + n - \dfrac{60}{d} &= 0 \\
   n &= \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{1+\dfrac{240}{d}}}{2} \\
\end{align}

The possible integer values of $\dfrac{240}{d}$ are 
$$\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 30, 40, 48, 60, 80, 120, 240\}$$

We note that $1+\{3, 8, 15, 24, 48, 80, 120\}$ are perfect squares.

Which leads to $d \in \{80, 30, 16, 10, 5, 3, 2\}$

and $n \in \left\{\dfrac 12, 1, \dfrac 32, 2, 3, 4, 5\right\}$.

Removing the fractions, we end up with
$(n,d) = \{(1,30), (2,10), (3,5), (4,3), (5,2) \}$

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, Steven!  This is exactly what I was expecting... =)